# Commutative Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, commutativity

I find it a little annoying to type

```
(+) 0 a = a
(+) a 0 = a
(*) 0 _ = 0
(*) _ 0 = 0
-- etc.
```

The following is more or less what I am trying to do

```
f [] a = a
f a [] = a
f (1:1:as) (1:1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f as (0:bs))
f (1:1:1:as) (1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f (0:as) bs)
```

Is there a way to state that a function is commutative? As in, is there a way to state that so long as **any** of the parameters are a particular value, then the result should be so-and-so?

I imagine it must be quite difficult, for the compiler-writers, to define such a behaviour, but I have already been surprised many times by haskell.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the comments I have though of a way

```
f [] a = a
--f a [] = a
f (1:1:as) (1:1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f as (0:bs))
--f (1:1:1:as) (1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f (0:as) bs)
f a b = f b a
```

Though I imagine it must perform a little worse, since it has to check all the patterns, then flip then check again.

Comment: I would not be surprised if `f = flip f` worked...but it would not save any lines in your example.

Comment: I am unaware of how to make this happen, but I love the idea.  I assume that it would only be advantageous for domains over a finite set, where you pattern match each value, correct, though....  Am I wrong?  In that case I suppose you could fill in the upper diagonal then use a default case that flips and recursively calls, a bit like @arunasr mentioned, no?

Comment: Maybe the "commutativity monad" could help? https://github.com/gelisam/commutative

Comment: @arunasr I couldn't get f = flip f to work, ghci complains about "different number of arguments"

Though your comment led me to a solution, which I added to the OP

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @user1433771 I would imagine gchi complaint could be silenced by explicit type signature, like `f :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`

Comment: @jamshidh function domain does not have to be finite; you can have infinite subdomains defined by guards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I have though of a way

```
f [] a = a
--f a [] = a
f (1:1:as) (1:1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f as (0:bs))
--f (1:1:1:as) (1:1:bs) = [0,0] ++ (f (0:as) bs)
f a b = f b a
```

Though I imagine it must perform a little worse, since it has to check all the patterns, then flip then check again.